# File dictating how simple products display on product page

Tags: simple-product

Was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of the .phtml file that dictates how simple products are displayed on their parent configurable product pages?

I am running into an issue where the simple product and attributes (images / sku / etc) for these products that are out of stock are being removed from the configurable product page.

Looking at the 'configurable.phtml' file I cannot seem to find where this is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading all the allowed products attached to a configurable product the following code is called:

```
/**
 * Get Allowed Products
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllowProducts()
{
    if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()) {
        $products = array();
        $skipSaleableCheck = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck();
        $allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getUsedProducts(null, $this->getProduct());
        foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
            if ($product->isSaleable() || $skipSaleableCheck) {
                $products[] = $product;
            }
        }
        $this->setAllowProducts($products);
    }
    return $this->getData('allow_products');
}
```

The key that you are looking for is the line `if ($product->isSaleable() || $skipSaleableCheck) {` this will only allow the addition of saleable products unless overridden.

One option for you is to listen to the event `catalog_product_is_salable_after` and override the value of `is_salable`, note that there is a typo in Magento not my regarding saleable.